# Magento 2.1.5 Create Redirect in js method rendrer

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers, payment-methods

How to create a js redirect which will trigger the controller to redirect to a payment gateway

I am tring to create a payment gateway for magento 2.1.5 which will be redirected on the Bank

**EDIT1 No Success:**
After your reply I have implemented this in the model but there is not redirection happening

```
    namespace Vendor\CustomPayment\Model\Payment;

    class CustomPayment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
    {

        protected $_code = "CustomPayment";
        protected $_isOffline = true;

        public function isAvailable(
            \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
        ) {
            return parent::isAvailable($quote);
        }

        public function getCheckoutRedirectUrl()
        {
            return 'http://CustomPayment.com';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to ***redirect to bank page after  order place*** for **`your payment then at your payment method class`** your should add a function `getCheckoutRedirectUrl()`.

`getCheckoutRedirectUrl()` at this function your need to define at page url on which customer will redirect after order place

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]/[ModuleName]/[Model];
.....
class [PaymentClass] extends ....{
     public function getCheckoutRedirectUrl()
    {
        return 'http://example.com';
    }

}
```

**So after order place customer will redirect to example.com**

Comment: what class should [PaymentClass] be extended

Comment: I have modified my question with your answer but no success